# SQL join two records

Tags: sql, oracle, select, join

I have a query that outputs me rows like this

```
CODE|FIELD1|FIELD2|FIELD3|FIELD4|FIELD5|
A   | DATA1| DATA2|      |      |  XYZ |
A   |      |      | DATA3| DATA4|data5A|
```

I would like something like this

```
CODE|FIELD1|FIELD2|FIELD3|FIELD4|FIELD5|
A   | DATA1| DATA2| DATA3| DATA4|data5B|
```

How can I do that?
'Code' isn't UNIQUE.
Actually this query produces a result-set with multiple rows so I have to pair someone

Comment: Is the `code` field unique to each pair?

Comment: rows like this? do you mean two rows?

Comment: I have hundred of rows like this..A is not unique, sorry

Comment: Why is `xyz` chosen over `qwe` in the column 5?

Comment: How should query decide what to display in Field5? (`XYZ` or `QWE`?) alphabetically descending ? - remember, there is no implicit order in relational database tables.

Comment: XYZ, QWE are just two different data. I need to merge 2 pairs of rows

Comment: @MichaelJohnks. Did you try using if sentence, if t1.code == t2.code then t1.code else CONCAT(t1.code, T2.code) and so on...

Comment: How can I use a IF in a Query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A neat trick you can use here is to use the `max` (or `min`) aggregate function - it will ignore `null`s, so the only value in the column would also be the maximal value in the column:

```
SELECT   code,
         MAX(field1) AS field1,
         MAX(field2) AS field2,
         MAX(field3) AS field3,
         MAX(field4) AS field4,
         MAX(field5) AS field5
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY code
```

Answer (score 0):

Use This query

```
    SELECT 
      CODE,
      MAX(FIELD1) AS FIELD1,
      MAX(FIELD2) AS FIELD2,
      MAX(FIELD3) AS FIELD3,
      MAX(FIELD4) AS FIELD4,
      MAX(FIELD5) AS FIELD5 
    FROM
      TABLE 
    GROUP BY CODE
```

Comment: what is not working? are you getting different result?

Comment: lol - so this is not working, and the **exact** same query posted by someone else is marked "correct"? How does that go?